# SQL Server Trigger with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a SQL Server `after insert` trigger with two conditions as shown below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @smstext AS NVARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @FromMobile AS NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @InLogID BIGINT
    DECLARE @SMSCTime DATETIME

    IF (SELECT @a = [a], @b = [b], @c = c, @d = d  
        FROM inserted 
        WHERE xyz = 123)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO [table_Staging].[dbo].[table_column1] (E, M, F, G, H) 
        VALUES (@b, @d, @c, RTRIM(LTRIM(@a)), GETDATE());

    IF (SELECT @a = [a], @b = [b], @c = c, @d = d  
        FROM inserted 
        WHERE xyz = 456)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO [table_Staging].[dbo].[table_column2] (E, M, F, G, H) 
        VALUES (@b, @d, @c, RTRIM(LTRIM(@a)), GETDATE());
    ENDIF
 END
```

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work." is not a problem description. Why doesn't it work? Error? Unexpected results?

Comment: If I give one select statement (or one condition) it works but if I try to use two select statements with IF ELSE condition, then it fails...

Comment: "it fails" tells us very little, **how** does it fail?

Comment: doesn't execute at all

Comment: Bear in mind that triggers fire one per *statement*, not once per row. The `inserted` table contains *all* affected rows - which may be 0, 1 or *multiple* rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish here.... your `IF` doesn't do any comparison or anything - so it's really not valid as is stands.

I can only guess - are you trying to **check** if a row with a given `xyz` exists in `Inserted` ?? Also - you're using `@a` and many more variables - but those are not **defined** anywhere...... this is really quite a messy question!

Since nothing will be done (no rows will be inserted) if a row doesn't really exist in `Inserted`, you can make this quite simple:

```
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [table_Staging].[dbo].[table_column1] (E, M, F, G, H) 
        SELECT [b], c, d, RTRIM(LTRIM([a])), SYSDATETIME()
        FROM inserted 
        WHERE xyz = 123

    INSERT INTO [table_Staging].[dbo].[table_column2] (E, M, F, G, H) 
        SELECT [b], c, d, RTRIM(LTRIM([a])), SYSDATETIME()
        FROM inserted 
        WHERE xyz = 456
END
```

Comment: Thanks, Marc. Sorry about the confusion. What I am looking for is when the main table gets inserted with xyz = 123, it should insert the mentioned values into the first table 'table_column1' and if main table inserts with xyz=456, it should insert the mentioned values into the second table 'table_column2'.

Comment: @muddu83: updated my response - the second, simpler version should do the trick, I believe

Comment: Super! That's brilliant.